# where's definition of __SetPageReferenced in kernel sources

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I try to port some functionality from newest stable kernel (4.6.3) to older one for whatever reason I've got for doing so. Everything went pretty good but I keep getting `mm/filemap.c:1183:4: error: implicit declaration of function '__SetPageReferenced'`

I cannot find oryginal definition of 
`static inline void __SetPageReferenced(struct page *page)` which is funny considering that oryginal 4.6.3 compiles no problem despite fact I can't find that definition in it's sources

Forgot to mention, there are similar declarations in `include/linux/page-flags.h` I would just copy and paste it right here if I knew where to find it. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find any useful mention of it anywhere online.

So thanks to the conversation in comment section, especially to @LPs input I came up with sort of a hack where I define:
`#define __SetPageReferenced(page)  set_bit(PG_referenced, &(page)->flags)` which get rid of the implicit declaration problem. I'll post whether it works or not when I finally port my functionality and base on the results might reopen or close the question.

Cheers!

Side note:
Found out that you can use `extern void mark_page_accessed(struct page *);` instead while fixing different problem.

Comment: Have you also checked the header files? That `static inline` indicates that the function might be defined in a header file.

Comment: Linux Cross Reference (LXR) is a great resource for digging into questions as such: http://lxr.free-electrons.com

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks, but I wouldn't write here if I wouldn't already tried it and failed.
@JoachimPileborg there's no header for `filemap.c` in `include/linux/` any more in 4.6.3 apparently. But too be sure I'll check sub folders again with recursive search. Also checked all headers that are included in filemap. Greping recursively through whole kernel doesn't bring back anything useful.

Comment: there is a definition of `SetPageReferenced` into [mm.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm.h?v=2.4.37) but not for `__SetPageReferenced`....mmmmm strange....

Comment: I've got this special thing about me, I always find all sorts of weird bugs and problems with software. Usually ones that are hard to reproduce and even harder to fix. Apparently that's useful in CS :D

Comment: It was introduced into 3.17 kernel release.

Comment: @LPs I'll look for it's sources and update if I'll find anything, thanks for this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare macro `__SETPAGEFLAG` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h?v=4.6#L198), use it for `referenced` bit [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/page-flags.h?v=4.6#L256)
Result:

```
static __always_inline void __SetPageReferenced(struct page *page)         \
 { __set_bit(PG_referenced, &PF_HEAD(page, 1)->flags); }
```

Comment: Thanks to your post I've figured out those macros. Thanks a lot!